# Passing state value to mapDispatchToProps in React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

**DISCLAIMER:** *I just started learning React and Redux, so may be this is a noob question, but please bear with me.*

So, here is the short form of my problem:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import someComponent from 'some_file_that_exports_component_as_default_export' 

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ state })

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
    fetchComplianceLink() {
     dispatch({
      type: 'ACTION_TYPE',
      payload: {
        someKey: <XYZ>, // --> this value (XYZ) I want from my state
      },
     })
    },
})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(someComponent)
```

I tried with mergeProps as well, but didn't get any success. May be my approach is wrong, or may be **mergeProps** is not the function that might fix this. Please shed some light. How could I get the value of **XYZ** from **state**

Thanks in Advance &
Happy Coding
:)

Answer (score 2):

You can not pass state of store (dynamic state) to `mapDispatchToProps`, It just return an object have functions that you define and help you `how to dispatch` and `what dispatch to do`.
You need to do:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    key: state... // get value of store here to pass into Component
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    fetchComplianceLink(value) {
        dispatch({
           type: 'ACTION_TYPE',
           payload: {
               // someKey: <XYZ>, // --> this value (XYZ) I want from my state
               someKey: value
           },
        })
    },
})
```

Use `fetchComplianceLink` in `Component`:

```
ComponentDidMount() { // or ComponentWillMount
    const { key, fetchComplianceLink } = this.props;
    // Call fetchComplianceLink with key got from store
    fetchComplianceLink(key);
}
render () {
    return (

    )
}
```